# Converting DPX to JPEG2k in RGB using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, rgb, jpeg2000

I am attempting to use FFMPEG to convert a 2k DPX sequence that is 10 bit RGB into a Lossless JPEG2k wrapped in MXF, 10 bit with RGB colorspace, wrapped in MXF, Op1a. The following is my code -

ffmpeg -y -i \PATH\test\0%05d.dpx -r 24 -c:v libopenjpeg -pred 1 c:\temp\123.mxf

The conversion works in almost every fashion, the exception being the JPEG file is output as YUV with every conversion attempt. I have tried using the jpeg2000 library as well, that always gives an 8 bit output, YUV.

FFMPEG -version responds - N-85179-gdc1a1b8

There is no audio accompanying the video.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 24 -i \PATH\test\0%05d.dpx -c:v libopenjpeg -pix_fmt gbrp10le 123.mxf
```

Although to be honest, if the input is RGB, ffmpeg should automatically output RGB for this encoder.

Comment: First of all, thanks you, that does work, but turns out, so does the original code.

Comment: I was using Mediainfo to check the input and output files formats, and it was (and still does in both cases) report the output MXF file as YUV. When I saw that I figured it was time to double check, and sure enough, FFPROBE identifies the output MXF as RGB. I ran the original code, same thing.

Comment: NOW I need to find a third source to identify the file format, off to the OPENCUBE I go!

Comment: Well THAT didnt go as I hoped, Opencube Identifies the new file (either from original code or second string) as CBYCRY. It also doesnt even try to play it, the file crashes the decoding. Back to the drawing board

Comment: Which app is ultimately going to use the file?

Comment: just wonder if this does work or does not work. I met the same issue as OP, cannot create RGB mxf too.